# Does every commutative idempotent semigroup have a representation as a union-closed family of sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, semigroups

Consider a finite semigroup $S$ whose semigroup operation $\times$ is commutative and whose elements are idempotent.

Does there exist a finite union-closed family of finite sets $\mathcal{M}$ such that there is a bijection $\tau: S \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ where $\forall a,b \in S, \tau(a \times b) = \tau(a) \cup \tau(b) $?

I feel that this may not be the case necessarily since I haven't encoded any information about "subsets,containment..." into the axioms i've stipulated on the semi group, but from a purely algebraic standpoint it would seem that this characterizes the union very well.

Comment: Retag your question, it is not set theory.

Comment: Re tagged to combinatorics since family of union closed sets originates from there

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Given $a\in S$, consider the set $I(a)=\{b\in S:ab=b\}$.  I claim that that $I(ab)=I(a)\cap I(b)$. Indeed, if $c\in I(a)\cap I(b)$ then $(ab)c=a(bc)=ac=c$ so $c\in I(ab)$.  Conversely, if $c\in I(ab)$, then $ac=a(abc)=a^2bc=abc=c$ so $c\in I(a)$, and similarly $c\in I(b)$.  Also, if $I(a)=I(b)$, then $a\in I(b)$ and $b\in I(a)$ so $a=ab=b$.

So, this is almost what you wanted, but with intersections instead of unions.  To get unions, you can just take complements and define $\tau(a)=S\setminus I(a)$ and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the image of $\tau$.

Semigroups of this sort are known as [(unbounded) semilattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) and are a basic object of study in order theory.  They are often thought of as ordered sets via the ordering $a\leq b$ if $ab=b$ (or $ab=a$, depending on the context); the algebraic structure can then be defined in terms of the ordering.

Comment: Ah, I had basically the same idea, but I was trying to define it using unions and kept failing at one point in the proof.

Comment: If I undelete my answer, could you take a look and tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: @M.Vinay: I can see it even while it's deleted.  Your approach is basically the same as defining $\tau(a)=\{b\in S:ab=a\}$.  That typically won't satisfy $\tau(ab)=\tau(a)\cup\tau(b)$.  Indeed, suppose the operation on $S$ really is $\cup$.  Then $\tau(ab)=\tau(a)\cup\tau(b)$ would be saying $c\subseteq a\cup b$ iff $c\subseteq a$ or $c\subseteq b$, which isn't true in general.

Comment: The corresponding fact for intersections is true, though: $c\subseteq a\cap b$ iff $c\subseteq a$ and $c\subseteq b$.  That's why it's more natural to first get a representation where the operation becomes intersection, as in my answer.

Comment: Ah, nice argument, I see the problem now. Thank you so much!